# Jquery pull json data from html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, json

I added a data to html via NodeJS Express, and with .setHeader, I got the html title as json. Pull data from html in JS file and send it to another html file only as title for each title.

There is the JavaScript code,

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get("/admin/getposts", null, function (data) {

       // Main bir div oluşturmak
        $(".postsMain").html("");

        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
          
        // Div 2 için html ayarlamak
        var html += "<div class='postsAlt'>";
            html += "<p>" + i.title + "</p>"
            html += "</div>";

            // Div 2'leri div1 lere aktarmak
            $(".postsMain").append(html);
        });

    }, "json").done(function() {
      console.log('Başarıyla data çekildi') 
    }) 
});
```

There is the pull data in NodeJS

```js
app.get("/admin/getposts", (req, res) => {
  let titles = [];
  Object.entries(postData.all()).forEach((entry) => {
    const [ID, data] = entry;
    titles.push(data.data)
  });


  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  res.send(JSON.stringify(titles));
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why not use `.getJSON()` instead? https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: I tried, but I still didn't get any results.

Comment: Please check your Console and Network tabs to see if there are any Errors shown or Requests / Responses.

Comment: I've tried that a lot, too, and there's no mistake, there's no log.

Comment: You should see the Request and the Response in the Network section. Does the Response contain JSON data? What does it show? There has to be some detail or activity. Maybe add some `console.log()` entries in your code to help log activity step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Some corrections to your code.

```
$(function () {
  $.getJSON("/admin/getposts", function (data) {
    $(".postsMain").empty();
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
      var alt = $("<div>", {
        class: "postsAlt"
      }).appendTo(".postsMain");
      $("<p>").html(item.title).appendTo(alt);
      console.log('Başarıyla data çekildi'); 
    });
  });
});
```

In your Each loop, you used `i` for the Index and `item` for the Value. So `i.item` should have thrown an error about being undefined. I switched it to `item.title` which should give the proper detail.

I also updated the code to use jQuery to create the new HTML Elements.

Comment: I'm sorry to keep you busy before and now, but I found the source of the problem. The jQuery script was lower than listPost.js, so it didn't work, so I'm sorry again.